# Empty field in view while it has been retrieved with dd Function

Tags: laravel

I have joined two tables in Clint table controller and Appointment table as below image and dd function showing the data already.

Here is my controller:

[image]

and here is result of dd():

[image]

but in the view page it's an empty field:

[image]

and here is available I am using in the view:

[image]

Comment: add your code in the question as code. don't just post images of code.

Comment: Clint controller

Comment: public function show(Client $client)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('client_show'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        
        $client = DB::table('clients')
        ->join('appoinments', 'clients.Id', '=', 'clint_id')
        ->select('clients.*', 'appoinments.start_time', 'appoinments.finish_time')
       
       
        ->first();
        

        return view('admin.clients.show', compact('client'));

Comment: Clint view <td>
                                        {{ $client->start_time }}
                                    
                                    </td>

Comment: its working now :) thank you , but now its showing only data for first Clint ID for all clients

Comment: as you are using `first()` this retrieves the first matched row from the database and thus you are getting only one client. use `get()` and loop through the collection to get all the clients. and i would suggest you to use eloquent relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your controller image and in join statement mistake.

When you `join` your `appointment` table to the `clients` table then you should use foreign keys.

```
public function show(Client $client) { 
    abort_if(Gate::denies('client_show'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden'); 

    $client = DB::table('clients') ->join('appoinments', 'clients.id', '=', 'appoinments.clint_id') ->select('clients.*', 'appoinments.start_time', 'appoinments.finish_time') ->get();


    return view('admin.clients.show', compact('client'));
}
```

I assume in the appointment table you have `clint_id`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$client` that you are passing to your view is from your Route Model Binding. `$clients` is the result of your query with the join to `appointments` which provides the fields `start_time` and `finish_time`. You are showing us the output of a `dd` on `$clients` which includes those fields, but passing `$client` to your view which most likely does not have such fields.

You could adjust what you are passing to your view to fix this:

```
return view('admin.clients.show', [
    'client' => $clients,
]);
```

I am not sure what your purpose is with this method though as the route parameter doesn't end up being used. You probably want to be using that route parameter to filter your query. Though this could be a good place to try using relationships instead of directly joining with query builder.

Also, please do not put up pictures of code. Please edit your question and include the code into the question if you can. Thanks.

[Laravel 6.x - Docs - Routing - Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: sorry but i'm a beginner in laravel and   stack overflow i thought images might help more , anyway I've corrected my variables and its working now thanks for the support .